# Form input using jQuery and conditionals

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

New to this! Trying to change the behavior of a HTML form using jQuery. So far if no field is filled out they all get a red border. I would like to make it that if either field isn't filled out (and the others are) only that field will get the border to highlight that it hasn't been filled. I would then hope to add alerts to each of these. TIA.

```
<div class="row">
  <form class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group" id="form">
      <label for="name">Name</label>
      <input placeholder="Enter your name" class="form-control" type="text" id="name" required="required">

    </div>
    <!-- end form group -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">Email address</label>
      <input placeholder="Enter your email" class="form-control" type="email" id="email" required="required">
    </div>
    <!-- end form group -->

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="message">Message</label>
      <textarea placeholder="Your message here...." class="form-control message-box" style="resize: none" cols="40" rows="5" id="message"></textarea>
      <p id="char-count"></p>
      <p id="visible-comment"></p>
      <p id="submit"><a class="btn btn-default" role="button">Submit &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>
    <!-- end form-group -->
    <h3 id="message-reply">Thank You</h3>

  </form>
```

JQuery

```
$("#submit").on('click', function() {
  var comment = $('.message-box').val();
  var formControl = $('.form-control').val();

  if (formControl === '') {

    $('.form-control').css('border', '2px solid red');
  } else {

    // $('#visible-comment').html(comment);
    $('.form-group').hide('slow');
    // $('.message-box').hide('slow');


    $('#message-reply').show();

    console.log(comment);
    return false;
  };
});
```

Comment: what is the issue ?

Comment: I'm trying to make individual fields highlight when there is no input, not all of them. So, if only the name field is filled, I want the other two fields to highlight. It's down to conditional statements, but I can't seem to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

`$('.form-control').val()` will only return the value of the first element with that class found in the page

You need instance specific ones which can be isolated in an `each` loop.

I'm not going to write the whole thing but will give you a reasonable starting point:

```
$("#submit").on('click', function() {
  // validation flag
  var formIsValid = true;
  // loop over all the form control class in page (make selector more specific as needed)
  $('.form-control').each(function() {
    // "this" is the current instance
    var $input = $(this);
    // does current input have a value?
    if (!$input.val()) {
      // failed validation so set flag to false
      formIsValid = false;
      // add error class rules in your css as needed
      $input.addClass('error')
    } else {
      $input.removeClass('error')
    }
  });
  // if no problems above then this will be true and form will submit
  // if using ajax return false but check formIsValid before sending data
  return formIsValid;
});
```

Comment: Thanks...a little advanced, so maybe what i'm asking is too complicated for me!

Comment: Never learn if you don't work with challenges. I understand that as a beginner the learning curve is quite steep but every step forward helps lessen the curve

Comment: Thanks. I thought I could just  alter my code to say that 'if  a field (i.e. form-control name) wasn't filled it would highlight, otherwise it would not highlight, and if all fields were filled the form would send, and display the 'message-reply'?

Comment: well you can use ID's and look at each ID. Or when there are several the norm is to loop over the collection of them in a loop like i did and look at each instance inside the loop. The first way requires a lot more code and can run into more spaghetti logic than needed

Comment: ah ok, i sort of remember loops, will need to do some research. thanks

Comment: Well i've spent days trying to achieve what I would like and not getting anywhere. Would anyone be able to help? My experience with loops is very limited so a little more help with the above answer would help....TIA